# What is the cardinality of Dana Scott's $D_{\infty}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, domain-theory

In the 1960's, Dana Scott constructed the domain $D_{\infty}$ which has the property
$D_{\infty} \cong D_{\infty}{}^{D_{\infty}}$.

Its construction is based on a cumulative hierarchy of infinite sequences.

For an exposition of its construction one can read the Stenlund (1972) book, “Combinators, $\lambda$-terms and proof theory", Ch1 §6.

Assume that we know the cardinality of $\lVert D_0\rVert = d$.

Then $D_1 = D_0 {}^{D_0}$, so $\lVert D_1\rVert = d^d$.

$D_2 = D_1{}^{D_1}$, so $\lVert D_2\rVert = {(d^d)}^{(d^d)} = d^{d^{(d+1)}}$.

In general, $D_{n+1} = D_n{}^{D_n}$.

Is there a way to express $\lVert D_{\infty}\rVert$ in terms of $d$?

Or, in the finite case, a nice formula for $\lVert D_n\rVert$?

Comment: I'm afraid I might be missing something. Assuming $A^A$ means the set of $A$-indexed sequences from $A$, and $\cong$ is something that implies bijection, then it is impossible to have a set with more than one element satisfying $A^A\cong A$. So either I'm missing what $A^A$ means or what $\cong$ means.

Comment: Thanks for asking this, maybe I messed up the description. What you asked is precisely Dana Scott's contribution, and it started the field known as domain theory. The correct notation is $D_{\infty} \cong D_{\infty} \rightarrow D_{\infty}$. This seemingly paradoxical statement is achieved by a slightly different notion of function application (always going from $D_{n}$ to $D_{n-1}$).  Independent of this issue, I guess my question is still valid, right?

Comment: I don't know anything about domain theory, but let me reiterate - there is no set $A$ with more than one element which is equipotent to the set of functions $A\to A$.

Comment: PS:  Scott was trying to find a model for the untyped $\lambda$-calculus, in which functions can apply to themselves.

Comment: @Wojowu  This is achievable by a suitably defined notion of continuous functions, known as Scott-continuous.

Comment: Scott's models are directed-complete partial orders (DCPOs), which form a cartesian closed category, and the exponential $A^B$ of two DCPOs does not consist of all *functions* from $B$ to $A$, but only those which preserve directed joins. Therefore it is not correct to say that $|A^B| = |A|^{|B|}$ (the cardinal exponential on the right counts all functions). I may come back to say more about the question, but there is nothing shocking going on.

Comment: In light of @ToddTrimble's comment, I am not sure if your question remains well-founded, since his comment seems to indicate that some of your assertions about cardinalities is incorrect. Moreover, I don't quite understand what you expect the cardinality to be; if each $D_n$ is finite then the cardinality of $D_\infty$ is going to either be finite or countably infinite. Todd's comment also seems to indicate that cardinality is not really the right notion of "size" for $D_\infty$ anyway

Comment: When $|D_{0}|=\omega$, you get [$|D_{\infty}|\cong\varepsilon_{0}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)), don't you?

Comment: @AlexNelson Ordinal exponentiation is about something else altogether.

Comment: @AlexNelson And in fact $\epsilon_0$ is countable.

Comment: @AlexNelson  If its ordinal is like $\epsilon_0$ then wouldn't its cardinal number be $\aleph_0$?

Comment: TeX note:  please use $\|D\|$ `\|D\|` rather than $||D||$ `||D||` for better spacing.  I edited accordingly.  (I also think that $D_n^{D_n}$ `D_n^{D_n}` is much more common than $D_n{}^{D_n}$ `D_n{}^{D_n}`, but the latter was obviously intentional, so I didn't change it.)

Comment: @YemonChoi: That is incorrect, $D_\infty$ is either trivial or uncountable, depending on $D_0$. And it is not at all the case that a limit of finite object need be finite. Already the cartesian product of countably many sets of size two is uncountable.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you for correcting my earlier misunderstanding/stupidity. I am still not sure that the cardinality of $D_{\infty}$ itself is of interest, but of couse the asymptotics of the cardinalities of the stages in the construction could be interesting. I was just a bit puzzled by the OP seeking some expression for the cardinality of $D_\infty$ in terms of the cardinality of $D_0$

Comment: @AndrejBauer regading your second comment/example, I guess I was thinking carelessly of colimits of finite sets / finite-dimensional vector spaces / etc. But as you point out, these are limits here, not colimits.

Comment: @YemonChoi  I think I have found a model of untyped $\lambda$-calculus in the Hilbert space of continuous functions, Dana Scott's work being the inspiration.  The structure of $D_{\infty}$ somewhat suggested Hilbert space to me, so I asked this to know more background :)

Comment: @YKY I am instinctively sceptical: how are you getting a Hilbert space of _continuous_ functions? It can't be an $L^2$-space...

Comment: @YemonChoi  If you're interested you may take a look:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AhQS3fp4WMFIDEhn_q4vNs-YJaq4Z-Fr/view?usp=sharing . I'd be very grateful if you can give some comments or spot some mistakes therein.  My email is there, thanks :)

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have the time to go over other people's projects. Could you please at least update your original question to take account of the errors pointed out by @ToddTrimble?

Comment: @YemonChoi  Fine, I'm trying to find a simple way to explain that without losing the intuition...

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks for the clarification. I'm afraid I've got sets on the brain ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you take $D_0$ to be the two-element chain, $D_1\cong(D_0\to D_0)$  is the **three**-element chain consisting of **order-preserving** endofunctions of $D_0$ (not a $4=2^2$-element set). Then $D_2$ is a lattice with **ten** elements  (not $27=3^3$).

It is then a combinatorial question how big the subsequent lattices are; maybe someone can find the sequence using suitable software.

In the limit, there are countably many compact elements of  $D_\infty$. The classical cardinality of $D_\infty$ is that of $P{\mathbb N}$.

Then $D_\infty\cong[D_\infty\to D_\infty]$, meaning the domain of functions that preserve directed joins.

Dana Scott discovered this and the "$P\omega$" model of the untyped $\lambda$-calculus after previously believing there was no "mathematical" model of it.  (Of course he knew from Church–Rosser that it is syntactically consistent.)

See [Scott on the consistency of the lambda calculus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16752/scott-on-the-consistency-of-the-lambda-calculus) for further discussion of that history.

I'm struggling to find where Scott first introduced the $D_\infty$ model, but there is a paragraph about it in
[*An Outline of a Mathematical Theory of Computation*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242406560_Outline_of_a_Mathematical_Theory_of_Computation).

I removed the "cardinality" tags from this question because they are misleading, cf. @Wojowu's ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382206/what-is-the-cardinality-of-dana-scotts-d-infty#comment971620_382206) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382206/what-is-the-cardinality-of-dana-scotts-d-infty#comment971623_382206)) and @ToddTrimble's ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382206/what-is-the-cardinality-of-dana-scotts-d-infty#comment971635_382206)) comments above.

Comment: The size of $D_n$ is $\binom{2n+1}{n}$, as in http://oeis.org/A001700

Comment: What is a compact element?

Comment: @LSpice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_element

Comment: @MattF. Why is that? I can’t find anything relevant in the (long) comment section of that OEIS page.

Comment: In fact, since $D_2$ has height $7$, $D_3=D_2\to D_2$ contains a copy of $\{1,\dots,7\}\to\{1,\dots,7\}$ (where $\{1,\dots,7\}$ is linearly ordered). The size of the latter is $\mathrm{A001700}(6)=\binom{13}6=1716$, much more than $\mathrm{A001700}(3)=\binom73=35$.

Comment: A (probably very crude) lower bound: it is easy to see that if $P$ is a finite lattice of height $h+1$, then $P\to P$ includes a copy of $P\to\{0,\dots,h\}$, which has height $h|P|+1\ge(h+1)h+1>h^2+1$. It follows by induction on $n$ that $D_{n+1}$ has height (and therefore size) more than $2^{2^n}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek By considering anti-chains I imagine you could get a qualitatively bigger lower bound than that, with $f(n)=2^{f(n)}$.

Comment: You mean $f(n+1)=2^{f(n)}$, I suppose. Yes, I agree the true rate of growth should be something like that.